# C Program - Do - while loops not working

Tags: c

My target output is after users entering a number >2 & <20 (result show) then program continue asking users enter another number. Or if users enters number <=2 or >=20, it will not show result but just re-asking users to enter number.

My Current Output:  If I input number <=2 || >=20, it will re-ask. but if I enter number between 2 and 20. It will just stops which suppose to be keep asking for entering new numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 20

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int random_array[MAX][MAX];
    unsigned int r, c, x, y;

    do {
        printf("Number Matrix in array ? ");
        scanf("%d", &c);

        system("cls");

        r = c;
        if (c>2 && c<20) {
            r = c;
            for (x = 0; x <= r - 1; ++x)
            {
                for (y = 0; y <= c - 1; ++y)
                {
                    random_array[x][y] = -1;
                }
            }
            for (x = 0; x <= r - 1; ++x)
            {
                for (y = 0; y <= c - 1; ++y)
                {
                    if (x == y)
                        random_array[x][y] = 0;
                    else
                        if (x<y)
                            random_array[x][y] = 1;

                    printf("%4d", random_array[x][y]);
                }

                puts("");
            }

            system("pause");
        }
    } while (c<=2 || c >=20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it always stop after the first time regardless of what you input? What numbers did you input? Does the program quit completely? Or is it getting stuck somewhere

Comment: I just checked again. If I input number <=2 || >=20, it will re-ask. but if I enter number between 2 and 20. It will just stops

Comment: Isn't that what you want though? If you enter a number that doesn't satisfy `c <= 2 || c >= 20` then you want it to quit running, which would quit the program.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: @MatthewKerian I want it keep running all over again regardless the number input in.

Comment: Then why not just do an infinite loop? `while (c<=2 || c >=20)` means that you want to run the loop while it satisfies those conditions. If you want it to continue regardless then why does it matter what the number is.

If you made it say `while(1)` then it would just keep running forever

Comment: this is because, I do not wanna show result if number <=20 or >=20. If they enter those numbers, I wanna program keep asking re-enter.

Comment: Aside on style: `x <= r - 1` is not idiomatic. It is more readable by humans as `x < r` and it can fail at the limits of the type range. For example `unsigned r = 0`.

Comment: @JamesMacathy Ahh, so what you want to do is change your do-while loop into an infinite loop. But then for the input part, surround that in a do-while loop, then you can make them re-enter input until it fits your specifications. Because right now it's going to go through all of your calculations before it realizes it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to prompt the user for input regardless of what they last input, you probably need an infinite loop. For this, replace your line with the `while` condition to this:

```
 } while (1);
```

This basically tells your program to loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition should be `while(c>2&c<20)`. But if you enter a number <=2 or >=20 the program will end and will not ask you for an input anymore. So the solution would be to use an infinite while loop and use break to end the loop when you want by using a condition.

Comment: `while (c > 2 & c < 20)` should be `while (c > 2 && c < 20)` Also I don't believe this is what he wants at all

Answer (score 0):

Your codes

```
do
{
    // show something
} while (c<=2 || c >=20);
```

means that it will stop after showing something if (c > 2 && c < 20), and that is exactly why your program quits after the condition is met.

To achieve your goal, consider using an infinite loop, and do different things using `if-else` inside the loop.

```
printf("Number Matrix in array ? ");
scanf("%d", &c);
system("cls"); 

if (c<=2 || c >=20)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    // show something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A do-while loop will run the block of code once, then will repeat until the while conditional evaluates to false.

```
do{

    //Stuff

}while (c > 20 || c < 2);
```

That would do the `//Stuff` part once, then it would do it again until c is either greater than 20 or less than 2.

What you want to do is surround the entire thing in an infinite loop, (either `for(;;)` or `while(1)`) so that it continues regardless.

But you also want to validate the input, so that's when you could use a do-while loop. When you're getting the scanf, you could do something like:

```
do{

    printf("Enter c: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

}while (c > 20 or whatever);
```

Then you could make him keep putting in c until it's the desired input!

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here's an example of putting the do-while inside the while:

```
while(1){

    do{
       printf("Enter a positive number: ");
       scanf("%d", &aNum);
    }while(aNum < 0);

    printf("Your positive number is %d.\n", aNum);

}
```

That would ask a user for input, and if he puts in a negative number it would ask him again. If it's a positive number it would print, then go back to the start and ask him for an input again.